# convert Python list to ordered unique values

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, set, ordereddictionary

I encounter many tasks in which I need to filter python (2.7) list to keep only ordered unique values. My usual approach is by using `odereddict` from collections:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

ls = [1,2,3,4,1,23,4,12,3,41]

ls = OrderedDict(zip(ls,['']*len(ls))).keys()

print ls
```

the output is:

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 23, 12, 41]

is there any other state of the art method to do it in Python?

- Note - the input and the output should be given as `list`

**edit** - a comparison of the methods can be found here:
https://www.peterbe.com/plog/uniqifiers-benchmark

the best solution meanwhile is:

```
def get_unique(seq):
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    return [x for x in seq if not (x in seen or seen_add(x))]
```

Comment: Does this information help you? https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

Comment: no, I'm not looking for ``sort`` options

Comment: I was going to post an answer but this thread is locked, have you checked out `deque` its `O(1)` time accessing the element from either end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to preserve the order **and** get rid of the duplicates, you can do it like:

```
ls = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 23, 4, 12, 3, 41]

lookup = set()  # a temporary lookup set
ls = [x for x in ls if x not in lookup and lookup.add(x) is None]
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 23, 12, 41]
```

This should be **considerably** faster than your approach.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) like this:

```
newls = []
seen = set()

for elem in ls:
    if not elem in seen:
        newls.append(elem)
        seen.add(elem)
```

Comment: sorry, but it looks even more complicated (for loop, two additional memory structures) than the original.

Comment: there is no need for the set

Comment: @Dimgold: yeah, it's a bit more verbose, but it doesn't require any `import`s and may well be more efficient than using `OrderedDict.keys`

Comment: can you elaborate about the complexity? I thinks they both are **O(n)**

Comment: @Dimgold - not all O's are born equal, your solution has an overhead of creating a doubly-linked list (and on the Python side as well). This one has some unnecessary function calls but I'm pretty certain the total amount of overhead is significantly lower than what you're using. Not even going into the memory overhead...

Comment: @Netwave (old comment, but thought I'd answer it), there is a need for the set. it will only be added to the set if it's not already there. if it's not, also add to the list - which keeps it ordered. so check with the set, and use in the end with the list (the set is a dummy thing there, kind of - since it's the one taking care of checking if the element already exists or not)

Answer (score 0):

Define a function to do so:

```
def uniques(l):
    retl = []
    for x in l:
        if x not in retl:
            retl.append(x)
    return retl
ls = [1,2,3,4,1,23,4,12,3,41]
uniques(ls)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 23, 12, 41]
```

Comment: pretty sure than this algorithm is at least **O(n^2)** (not counting the append ) while the original is **O(n)**

Comment: @Dimgold, actually is **O(n*log(n))** I think, but you avoid creating 3 intermediate structures.

Comment: why log? it's not sorted. I'm trying to figure out where are the bottlenecks. I'm pretty sure that from algorithmic point of view - @eugene proposal is the most efficient

Comment: @Dimgold, eugene is iterating over the same im doing, but creating a set, the lookup will be quicker probably for large list but the memory overhead will be larger too. if you print intermediate results from my retl and his lookup set is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be using list comprehension like this:

```
[x for i, x in enumerate(ls) if x not in ls[:i]]
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 23, 12, 41]
```

Comment: pretty sure than this algorithm is at least **O(n^2)** (not counting the append ) while the original is **O(n)**